# HTTP Post request of XML file in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, post

I have written some code for posting some xml data.
I am sending the request but , its throwing the exception while getting the response.

```
  string SendingXML = "<? xml version = \"1.0\" encoding = \"utf-8\" ?>< synchroMember >< memberUID >{EMAIL}:" + email + "</ memberUID >< dynContent >< entry >< key >{FIRSTNAME}</ key >< value >" + FirstName + "</ value ></ entry >< entry >< key >{LASTNAME}</ key >< value > " + LastName + "</ value ></ entry >< entry >< key >{EMVCELLPHONE}</ key >< value >" + phone + "</ value > </ entry >< entry >< key >{EMAIL}</ key >< value >" + email + "</ value > </ entry ></ dynContent ></ synchroMember >";
        string UIURL = paramsIUString;

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(UIURL);

        var postData = SendingXML;

        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData.ToString()); 

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        request.Accept = "application/xml";
        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

at, var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
its throwing the exception

[screen shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7quqj.png)

Kindly look into the issue.

Comment: The error message shows html error number 500. I would start by checking you web server is working.

Comment: Yeah I have done checking the web server but every thing is normal and working fine.  To be precise, There is another call i am making from to the server above and below these code . In both the cases its working fine. I guess there is some logical error in the code

Comment: I usually connect manually with an IE and capture results with a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Than compare results with my application code.  A lot of webpages return very little in error messages to prevent hackers from breaking into the webpages.  Error 500 could means lots of different issues.

Comment: Do you control the server you are posting the data to?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to see what is the error like this from the simple reason, you might send something wrong in your xml and your response is resulting in error. 
First thing I would have done here is work with fiddler. Check the session of this request and see what error it returns. It will be a lot easier for you to navigate through your problem then, because you will have a clue whether your xml is wrong, or something else.

Usually, when 500 is returned it means one of 2 things:

Either there is a problem with the service you are trying to connect. In this case, you will have to wait for the service to be fixed.

Or you are sending something incorrectly resulting in server error.